# If variable=string always returns true

Tags: javascript, html, forms, if-statement, passwords

I am having trouble with my javascript.

```js
function login() {
  var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  var combine = (username + password)
  if (combine = "userpassword") 
    alert("Logged in.")
  } else {
      alert("Incorrect username or Password.")
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<form id="login" onsubmit="return false;">
Username:<br>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username"><br>
Password:<br>
<input type="text" name="password" id="password"><br>
<input type="submit" type="POST" onclick="login();" />
</form>
```

As you can see, This is a login form. If i type it right, I get "Logged in."
But if i type t wrong; I get the same message.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

This is not a duplicate, As this post describes my problem, and I would have no way of knowing that the other post had the answers to my problem.

Comment: `if (combine = "userpassword") ` should be `if (combine === "userpassword") `

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Comment: @PMKRO Thanks! If you posted that as an answer, I'd have checked it.